# DAO Classes for each of the auxiliary tables?

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller

I'm doing a Java project using MVC, and I'm wondering if it's necessary create DAO classes for the auxiliary tables, or a DAO class for the involved classes should be enough. ex. for entities Player, Team, and Tournament with a relation many to many, Is it better a single class or four classes for each one of those?

Tell me if I'm being too vague. Greetings from Colombia.

Comment: I guess you need it if you're going to handle those objects seperately.

Comment: The Single Responsibility Principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) says that each DAO should be responsible for managing one thing, and one thing only.